# React Native Maintaining aspect ratio image ios

Tags: image, react-native

I have a 1242 X 450 image, which I’d like to display on a 1x 2x and 3x devices. The current code, which I have, works fine for 3x devices but I see that the edge of the image gets cropped on a 2x device and possible on a 1x device too.

In code I am setting width to 414 and height to 150 (because 1242 X 450 /3x)

Is there any way I can fix it?

The image is inside a list view

```
    <View style={styles.row}>
                    <Image
                    style={styles.featureImage}
                    source={{
                        uri: this.props.image_src
                    }}/>
    </View>


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    row: {
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor: 'lightgrey',
        flexDirection: 'row',
        margin: 6,
    },

    featureImage: {
        height: 150,
        width: 414
    }
});
```

Comment: Have a look at [react-native-scalable-image](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-scalable-image).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to deal with image's  size. You just give width and height property properly.

import Platform and get width and height of device.https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/dimensions.html

```
var {scrHeight, scrwidth} = Dimensions.get('window');
```

define an image container style

```
imageContainer = {
  width:scrwidth/5,
  height:scrHeight/5,
}
```

define image style and use resizeMode for image

> resizeMode enum('cover', 'contain', 'stretch', 'repeat', 'center')

```
imageStyle={ 
 flex:1,
}
<View style={styles.imageContainer }>
  <Image style={styles.imageStyle} resizeMode={'contain'}>
  </Image>
</View>
```

No matter how big the image is it will cover screenWidth/5 X screenHeight/5.
If your image has high resolution and device is not the image will be compressed in the contrary case it will be stretched. Both case especially second one if there is a big difference between image resolution and area which is left for image you will have bad image vision in your app. To avoid this situation you can add different sizes of the same image.

```
add 
└── img
    ├── apple@1x.png 100x100  (resolutions are random)
    └── apple@2x.png 150x150
        apple@3x.png 175x175
```

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images.html

If you do so proper image will be chosen by react automatically. Images are chosen according to dpi of device. If your device has nice resolution you get bigger image if not so smaller image. This situation mostly works except devices having big sizes and low resolutions( some android tablets). In this case according to dpi image will be probably smallest image so there will be a bad quality.